# Ubuntu 14.04 CPU fan issue

Tags: 14.04, cpu, overheating, fan, temperature

I just installed ubuntu 14.04 on my dell latitude e5450 and it doesn't seem like the cpu fan is working correctly. I had a 500 gb hdd in my computer and today took it out and installed a 240 gb ssd and am only booting ubuntu. I had ubuntu on that other hard drive and dont remember having this issue where my fans wouldn't turn on in my computer. Also when I run the sensors command in the terminal it produces the following output:

```
acpitz-virtual-0 Adapter: Virtual device temp1: +25.0°C (crit = +107.0°C) temp2: +27.8°C (crit = +105.0°C) temp3: +29.8°C (crit = +105.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000 Adapter: ISA adapter Physical id 0: +51.0°C (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C) Core 0: +51.0°C (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C) Core 1: +51.0°C (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

i8k-virtual-0 Adapter: Virtual device fan2: 0 RPM temp1: +51.0°C
temp2: +48.0°C
temp3: +42.0°C
temp4: +41.0°C
```

After restarting my computer I noticed that the fans were on when my computer was first started up but then after about a minute the cpu fan turns itself off.

Comment: Temps look OK. So what is the problem? Fans are not supposed to work all the time.